# Вместо русских символов "???"

Tags: php, laravel, utf-8

Вместо русских символов в панели Pterodactyl (написана на laravel) выводит "???". Установил , кодировку UTF-8. Не помогло. Перевод панели осуществляется в TypeScript файлах. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: для начала стоит убедиться что `utf-8` выбрана везде, а не только в одном наименее значимом месте. как минимум стоит проверить `php.ini`, `.htaccess`. `<? ini_set('....'); ?>`. +в некоторых местах может требоваться конкретизация(в столбцах mysql таблиц, если память не изменяет, нужно не просто `utf-8` а `utf-8 general-ci`).